# FileNotFoundException when using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Monitor.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-coverage

C# console app with a reference to `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\DataCollectors\x86\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Monitor.dll`:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeCoverage;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Monitor m = new Monitor();
        }
    }
}
```

The object creation line throws a `FileNotFoundException` with the message `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Monitor.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.`

Any idea why is this happening and how can be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> or one of its dependencies

Which is the relevant part of the error message.  It has a dependency on vspmsg.dll from that same directory, you'll have to copy it by hand into your bin\Debug folder.  Using private assemblies, exclusive to Visual Studio, is fairly courageous.

Comment: @Aliostad, probably because the library is not statically linked but dynamically loaded with `LoadLibrary` at runtime.

Comment: It is an assembly written in the C++/CLI language.  It contains unmanaged code.  The reason it needs the x86 target.  You can see the unmanaged dependencies it has with Dumpbin.exe /imports.  One for vspmsg.dll, named GetErrorMessageModule.  You're not allowed to distribute it, but if you'd do anyway then you need to have the C++ runtime DLLs deployed as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 references in this DLL (Here is what you find in ILDASM.exe):

```
.module extern **KERNEL32.dll**
.module extern **MSVCR100.dll**
.assembly extern **mscorlib**
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .hash = (AF 35 A4 2A B0 0E 9D FC 8A 27 B8 29 E5 56 7D 12   // .5.*.....'.).V}.
           18 84 3C 6B )                                     // ..<k
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}
.assembly extern **Microsoft.VisualC**
{
  .publickeytoken = (B0 3F 5F 7F 11 D5 0A 3A )                         // .?_....:
  .hash = (1B D7 52 11 F8 FD 90 65 01 8A 53 AA 7F 87 91 6D   // ..R....e..S....m
           F8 E3 72 91 )                                     // ..r.
  .ver 10:0:0:0
}
```

The first two are used as C DLL and the other two as .NET reference.
Have a look to make sure you have Microsoft.Visual (in the GAC) and MSVCR100.dll (somewhere on your machine which is also a Path).